# Getting specific information out of JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, google-maps

I am writing an app that requires the user to click on a location and then direct them to the location via Google Maps. I have thousands of locations stored in JSON format. I would like to be able to click the name of the location and have the app pull the coordinates from the file. I have this code so far.

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>ECC Site Lookup</h1>

    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="search" border="1" />
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs |filter : search ">
          <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=" + {{site.Point.coordinates}}> {{site.name}} </a>
        </li>"
        <li ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs |filter : search "></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I think what is wrong with this is the href portion. Specifically the {{site.Point.coordinates}}

Here is my JS code

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.SiteLocs = [{
        "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
        }

      }, {
        "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
        }
      }, {
        "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
        }];
angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location){


    // if last 2 characters in string are ",0"
    var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;


    if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength-2,clength)===",0")
    {
      location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0,clength-2);

    }

  });
  });
  }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't putting the coordinates inside the href, they are outside the quotes of the href.

```
 <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=" + {{site.Point.coordinates}}>
```

should be

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{site.Point.coordinates}}">
```

It appears you were trying to concatenate strings inside the html which won't work unless it is done inside `{{}}` expression braces.

```
<a href="{{'http://maps.google.com/?q=' + site.Point.coordinates}}">
```

Comment: This is partially wrong. [Do not use `href` with {{}} but ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref). Do not include the URI in the brackets!

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue of it not loading the links. But what i'm trying to figure out is how to have it load a single coordinate. because {{site.Point.coordinates}} is a couple thousand different coordinates.

Comment: @Pak it is not a problem within `ng-repeat` because the element can't exist until it is compiled anyway

Comment: @charlietfl okay, this might improve performances. But I still prefer the second syntax (no concatenation inside {{}} would be better)

Comment: @IanPennebaker you are misinterpreting the data. Each object has one set of cordinates. If you are trying to do something different than what is shown in html it isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I would probably make a wrapper function that you would use in place of the raw {{site.Point.coordinates}} in the template.

Make it take 'site' as the argument and return the coordinates that way. It could even be good to have it build the entire link, so that you have all that in the controller rather than the view.

Also couldn't you just do

`var clength = location.Point.coordinates.split[',']`

and then

`if(clength[clength.length-1] === '0')`

instead of all the hard-to-follow substring stuff?

Comment: That should work for another issue i'm having. Thanks!

Comment: If you have lodash in your project you could also use it's .last() method to get the last item in the array. :) Tally ho!

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate and (generally) use `ng-href` :

```
<a ng-href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{site.Point.coordinates}}">{{site.name}}</a>
```

Using Angular markup like `{{thing}}` in an `href` attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the `{{thing}}` markup with its value.

[Relevant angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

However, it is true that you don't need to use `ng-href` inside a `ng-repeat` because it has to be compiled first. You can still use `href` here.